# Merging two JSON Trees using Jerkson in Scala

Tags: json, scala

Seemingly simple thing to do, perhaps there's  built in routine in Jerkson, but I have written a simple merge function.  It is supposed to merge two JSON trees merging dictionaries and overwriting anything that is both in the source and update with the update value and taking anything in the update that isn't in the source.  I guess it's a personal choice as to what you want merged, so I could see there not being a built-in for this.  I wanted to verify there isn't a better way and that this way isn't stupid.

```
def merge(name: String, source: JObject, update: JObject) : JField = {
  JField(name, JObject(
    source.fields.map { x: JField =>
      // Do we have an updated value in our update
      findValue(x.name, update) match {
        // If so check what kind of value
        case Some(updatedField) => updatedField match {
          // If it's an object, merge it down
          case updatedObject: JObject => {
            x.value match {
              case sourceObject: JObject => merge(x.name, sourceObject, updatedObject)
              case other => JField(x.name, updatedObject)
            }
          }
          case other => other
        }
        case None => x
      }

    }
    // Concat with a list of fields that exist in the update and not in the source
    ::: (update.fields.filter { x =>
      findValue(x.name, source) match {
        case None => true
        case Some() => false
      }
    })
  ))
}
def findValue(name: String, obj: JObject) : Option[JField] = obj.fields.filter(_.name==name).headOption
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything out of the box with Jerkson, but the lift-json scala library has support for both merging and diffing json trees. I know you may be tied to Jerkson, so may not be able to use it directly, but it might be of interest to see how they implemented it. Documentation and source code is on github: https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json#merging--diffing